# Open new page with rails link_to and bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm having some problem to load a new page in a modal with bootstrap on Rails.

Here is the important part on my eventos/index.html.erb

```
<div id="content">        
  <% @eventos.each do |evento| %>
  <!--Bar 2-->
  <div class="mosaic-block bar2">
  **<%= link_to(evento, :class=>"mosaic-overlay", :id => "evento" , "data-toggle" =>     "modal", 'data-target' => '#eventoModal') do %>**
    <div class="details">
      <h4><%= evento.local %> - <%= evento.data.to_time.strftime('%e/%m') %></h4>
      <h4>Mais+</h4>
    </div>
    <%end%>
  <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><%= image_tag evento.attachment.url(:small) %></div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

As you can see there is a link_to to my "evento" (rendered html:

```
a href="/eventos/1" class="mosaic-overlay" data-target="#eventoModal" data-toggle="modal" id="evento"
```

But when I click the link, nothing happens (before add the modal it was working)

Here is evento/show.html.erb

```
<div class="modal" id="eventoModal">
     <p>Some code</p>
</div>
```

and finally on my assets/javascripts/eventos.js.coffe I have this:

```
$('#eventoModal').modal(options)
```

Anyone can help me show the evento/show.html.erb in a modal on the evento/index.html.erb page?

Answer (score 0):

I think your jQuery selector is wrong

```
$('#eventoModal').modal(options)
```

should be

```
$('#evento').modal(options)
```

Comment: Changed for your suggestion but still, nothing happens. Thanks for the reply